# What is this drill guide/template used when fixing electrical sockets called and where do I buy one?

Tags: electrical, tools

[image]

My dad used to have one, you use it as a drill guide/template when fixing electrical sockets, but I cannot find anywhere that sells them, and as I don't know the name Google is not much help!

(Searching on google for "socket drill template" did not find anything useful)

Comment: It's called a _pattress jig_.  I couldn't find any sellers in a quick search though.

Comment: Wow, what a memory you have.  I haven't seen one in years. Never would have remembered the name of that thing.

Comment: @Niall, thanks please make your comment into an answer so I can accept it,  I just found one on ebay http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/B-Q-Pattress-Jig-CUT-PATTRESS-BOXES-EASILY-NEW-/120660016019?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item1c17e5bb93 as you told me what to search for.

Comment: I'm curious, how did you manage to find that picture without knowing the name? Someone should make an online tool search engine where you can sketch a picture of a tool/jig/fixture and it tells you what it's called and where to find it.

Comment: @Shimon, see http://www.diy.com/diy/jsp/bq/templates/content_lookup.jsp?content=/content/knowledge/how_to/replace_socket/replace_socket.jsp&_loopback=1  when I googled for "socket template"

Comment: Ha, this question is already the 3rd result in a google search for "pattress jig".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called a *pattress jig*.

B&Q stock them in the UK.  However they can only be purchased from a physical store not online, the ean code is 03619377 and the cost is £7.68. (A B&Q store can order one if needed based on the ean code.)

There is also a seller on [eBay UK](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/B-Q-Pattress-Jig-CUT-PATTRESS-BOXES-EASILY-NEW-/120660016019?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item1c17e5bb93).

Answer (score 1):

The Pattress Jig available from B&Q is not great as using a template made out of plastic with a hammer drill means the template gets warped and damaged easily and doesn't hold straight on the wall.

I found this one on Amazon. Its made from Aluminium. Durable and holds nice and firm. Highly recommended at only £18.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pattress-Wall-Socket-Template-Electric/dp/B01E1LFU1M/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1478122129&sr=8-1&keywords=pattress+box+jig

It's made by these guys: http://www.mixengineering.co.uk/